# How to call back to files in an if statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, file-handling

I'm trying to make a code that takes a line from the file and prints it and then you type in an answer and if it matches another line it says 'correct'. that part is working but when we get to the 4th question it just keeps repeating and then gives an error.
In the text file the lines are separated by a '/'.

```
     def Q():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    while True:
        file = open("AA.txt", "r")
        for line in file:
            sec=line.split("/")
        print(sec[a])
        answer = input("Type your answer: ").strip()
        if answer == sec[b].strip() and b >8:
            print ("Correct!")
            a = a + 2
            b = b + 2
        elif answer == sec[b].strip() and b ==8:
                print ("Done.")
                break                
        else:
            print ("Wrong it's " + sec[b])
            a = a + 2
            b = b + 2
    file.close()

Q ()
```

This is the text file:

Slash separates stuff./When was the Battle of Hastings? 1066, 1078 or 1088/1066/When was the Great Fire of London? 1777 or 1666/1666/How many wives does Henry the VIII have? 8 or 6/6/When was the Wall Street Crash? 1929 or 1933/1929/

Comment: `==` is for comparison, and `=` is for assignment. Your `switch==True` lines don't do anything. You probably meant `switch=True`.

Comment: In addition to what @smarx said, you could just use `break` to exit the loop, and then get rid of the `switch` variable (use `while True` instead).

Comment: Sometimes when handling strings it is a good idea to blindly strip all whitespace from them before comparison, just in case there is trailing endlines and the like. So, do `answer = input("Type your answer: ").strip()` and `if answer == sec[b].strip():` instead. Maybe that's all you need.

Comment: So I did the .strip thing and changed to while True instead of while switch ==True and it's definitely working better. When I get to the 4th question, if I get it wrong it, it repeats the question and then whether I get it wrong or right it gives me this error code:
`When was the Wall Street Crash? 1929 or 1933
Type your answer: 12
Wrong it's 1929

Type your answer: 12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Yr 11\test AA.py", line 30, in <module>
    Q ()
  File "E:\Yr 11\test AA.py", line 11, in Q
    if answer == sec[b].strip() and b >8:
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @ArneRecknagel (ran out of characters).

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time finding the bug in your code. I'd say that the problem is that you wrote a while-loop and had to include some confusing control mechanisms that yielded strange results. I think you would be much better served writing your code in a way that the outer loop just iterates over the lines in your textfile - you will very rarely see while loops in python programs, for the simple reason that they are tricky, and a for-loop is usually what you want to do anyways.

So, if I understood your description correctly, this code here should more or less do the job, right? I assume a textfile with one question per line in the way you have specified they would look:

```
def ask_questions(filename):
  for line in open(filename, "r"):
    question, answer = line.strip().split("/")
    print(question)
    user_answer = input("Type your answer: ").strip()
    if user_answer == answer:
      print ("Correct!")
    else:
      print("Wrong, the correct answer is " + answer)
```